# how are webapck and system.js functionally different

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm coming across many websites and i could see there are some diff b/w both system.js and web pack, but i'm not able get what exactly they telling. can you tell that actual purpose of web pack and system.js and where they actually needed

Comment: @Sajeetharan I'm not able to understand from that post. Could you explain how they functionally different? it'll be grateful for me

Comment: you're asking the usage of both or the difference?

Comment: Yes..both... when to use them?? how they stand differently in module loading

Comment: the answer given above should have all the details. if you want more details you can modify this question. i would recomment to use webpack http://angularfirst.com/systemjs-to-webpack-before-you-begin/